# My code works in <script> tags but doesn't work in an external file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Was just wondering if someone could be able to help me out. I've come across a strange issue that i've never encountered and I have no idea how to solve it :

```
<head>
 <title>Welcome to Edge Hill Computing</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script>

     <script type = "text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">


</head>
```

my javascript file and my jquery file is imported here. Which "should" to the external jquery file. But it doesn't, i have to run the code from there with script tags. Any possible solution?

If it helps the code in the Global.js is this :

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtbox").keyup(function(){
        var name = $('#txtbox').val();
     $('#display').html((name));
    });
});
```

Comment: Try re-ordering your script tags so that your "global.js" is included after your jquery scripts.

Comment: The order of script tags matters, you should place your global.js tag after jquery, and you just need to load jquery once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

global.js should be loaded after jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Add your script tag after the jquery script references.

```
<head>
 <title>Welcome to Edge Hill Computing</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>
<script type = "text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>   
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script>

 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">


</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <head>
     <title>Welcome to Edge Hill Computing</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>
     <script type = "text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="global.js"></script>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">   
   </head>
```

You need to process your code after jquery has loaded.  I imagine when you were inserting it directly in the page it was below where you loaded jquery in the head tag.